# How can I deserialize this JSON in vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm using Google's cse Api and it outputs json. I would like to get just one of the elements from that json: "link" under "items". This is an example of the type of json the api outputs:

```json
{
  "kind": "customsearch#search",
  "url": {
    "type": "application/json",
    "template": "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={searchTerms}&num={count?}&start={startIndex?}&lr={language?}&safe={safe?}&cx={cx?}&sort={sort?}&filter={filter?}&gl={gl?}&cr={cr?}&googlehost={googleHost?}&c2coff={disableCnTwTranslation?}&hq={hq?}&hl={hl?}&siteSearch={siteSearch?}&siteSearchFilter={siteSearchFilter?}&exactTerms={exactTerms?}&excludeTerms={excludeTerms?}&linkSite={linkSite?}&orTerms={orTerms?}&relatedSite={relatedSite?}&dateRestrict={dateRestrict?}&lowRange={lowRange?}&highRange={highRange?}&searchType={searchType}&fileType={fileType?}&rights={rights?}&imgSize={imgSize?}&imgType={imgType?}&imgColorType={imgColorType?}&imgDominantColor={imgDominantColor?}&alt=json"
  },
  "queries": {
    "request": [
      {
        "title": "Google Custom Search - Dice",
        "totalResults": "1930000000",
        "searchTerms": "Dice",
        "count": 1,
        "startIndex": 1,
        "inputEncoding": "utf8",
        "outputEncoding": "utf8",
        "safe": "off",
        "cx": "a862b914da550aa30",
        "filter": "0",
        "gl": "ca",
        "hl": "fr",
        "searchType": "image"
      }
    ],
    "nextPage": [
      {
        "title": "Google Custom Search - Dice",
        "totalResults": "1930000000",
        "searchTerms": "Dice",
        "count": 1,
        "startIndex": 2,
        "inputEncoding": "utf8",
        "outputEncoding": "utf8",
        "safe": "off",
        "cx": "a862b914da550aa30",
        "filter": "0",
        "gl": "ca",
        "hl": "fr",
        "searchType": "image"
      }
    ]
  },
  "context": {
    "title": "Google"
  },
  "searchInformation": {
    "searchTime": 0.438051,
    "formattedSearchTime": "0.44",
    "totalResults": "1930000000",
    "formattedTotalResults": "1,930,000,000"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "customsearch#result",
      "title": "Dice - Wikipedia",
      "htmlTitle": "\u003cb\u003eDice\u003c/b\u003e - Wikipedia",
      "link": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/6sided_dice.jpg/1200px-6sided_dice.jpg",
      "displayLink": "en.wikipedia.org",
      "snippet": "Dice - Wikipedia",
      "htmlSnippet": "\u003cb\u003eDice\u003c/b\u003e - Wikipedia",
      "mime": "image/jpeg",
      "fileFormat": "image/jpeg",
      "image": {
        "contextLink": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice",
        "height": 826,
        "width": 1200,
        "byteSize": 99851,
        "thumbnailLink": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQP8ZJe7CxdEseanmeVnMY7-_ms7cBMkISUiCZyyRtGKMPpfF5LypoSGTc&s",
        "thumbnailHeight": 103,
        "thumbnailWidth": 150
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The rest of my programming is happening in vb.net (4.7.2) using visual studio. Currently, the variable response (string) is equal to the json above. How do I get just that one element and put it in it's own string variable?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you will want to do is to copy your JSON (shown above) so it is in your clipboard.

Then, in Visual Studio, create a new Class (call it "Blah" - it's just the filename, not the actual class, and you can rename it later). Delete the new class called "blah" in your new file so the file is empty.

From the menu in Visual Studio, select:

`Edit / Paste Special / Paste JSON As Classes`

Next you'll need to have installed the NuGet package called `Newtonsoft.Json` into your project. If you don't have it already, do it now. Then add this import at the top of the page where your code is:

`Imports Newtonsoft.Json`

Now in your code, after you have retrieved the JSON (from the source), lets pretend that you have stored that JSON in a variable called `sJSON`.

All you have to do is convert you JSON into the class you created by doing this:

`Dim MyTest As Rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(sJSON)`

And now you can find that URL here inside the object: `MyTest.items(0).link`

Comment: `MyTest.items` is an array or `List(Of String)`

Comment: I missed that. Thanks @Jimi

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
Dim theLink = JObject.Parse(json)("items").FirstOrDefault()?("link").ToString()
```

Replace `json` with the variable containing the JSON.